# Duplicate all data in the same table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicate-data

I'm looking for a way I can duplicate all the rows in my database, I tried exporting it and then importing but I get the duplicate key error.

The reason is purely for testing purposes, I just want a load of dummy data in there to test the system I have out.

Is there a direct statement for this? Or is there a way to export all data except ID (or change ID to `MAX(ID) + 1` or `AUTO INCREMENT`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name(parent_id,priority,text,shortname,weighting,g_or_a,
     dept,ksf,day_start,day_end,date_start,date_end,depends_on,is_question,budget,
     ccode,responsible,accountable,consulted,informed)
(SELECT parent_id,priority,text,shortname,weighting,g_or_a,dept,ksf,
    day_start,day_end,date_start,date_end,depends_on,is_question,budget,ccode,
    responsible,accountable,consulted,informed FROM your_table_name);
```

Firstly, insert one row in the table `'your_table_name'`. Replace `your_table_name` with the actual table name in above code & execute the code repeatedly until it satisfies the required row numbers. I think it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Put 1 record and then run:

```
insert into mytable select * from mytable
```

10 times. This will give you 1024 records. Continue until satisfied.

Comment: This still returns #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Ah, so you have primary key? Well, then make it AUTOINCREMENT specify field list in both INSERT and SELECT.

Comment: post it's structure, I'll give you exact query.

Comment: @AdamTester your link returns `File not found`

Comment: I removed it as it contained personal information but another answer already expanded on this one

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `INSERT` and the values would be a `SELECT`, just don't select the primary key and don't define it in the insert fields.

Imagine a table with 3 fields, `the_pk, field_1, field_2`

Something like

```
INSERT INTO the_table(field_1, field_2) (SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM the_table)
```